# MySQL Delimiter Error in my Trigger Query

Tags: mysql, triggers

This looks right to me,

But when I run it MySQL says.

> there is a syntax error at line 1 near 'delimiter'

This is my first trigger with MySQL. Please let me know if I'm doing something silly. Thanks!

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TR_ARCHIVE_UNITS $$
CREATE TRIGGER TR_ARCHIVE_UNITS
BEFORE DELETE ON unit_tracking
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO unit_tracking_HIST (id, dateAdded, unitCondition, make, model, unit_num, consign_flag, serial_num, description, gl_num, trade, invoice_posted, notes, deleted_date, user_deleted)
    SELECT id, dateAdded, unitCondition, make, model, unit_num, consign_flag, serial_num, description, gl_num, trade, invoice_posted, notes
    FROM unit_tracking
    WHERE id = OLD.id;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Where are you running the query from (gui client, API)?

Comment: GUI client. @MegaTron pointed out the problem. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change: `DELIMITER;` to `DELIMITER ;`

Comment: That WORKED!! Can you explain why? Maybe...Seems strange.

Comment: You're actually specifying ; as an argument to the DELIMITER command